# What is the best general purpose computing practice in OpenCL for iterative problems?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu, processing-efficiency, gpu-shared-memory

When we have a program that requires lots of operations over a large data sets and the operations on each of the data elements are independent, OpenCL can be one of the good choice to make it faster. I have a program like the following:

```
while( function(b,c)!=TRUE)
{
    [X,Y] = function1(BigData);
    M = functionA(X);
    b = function2(M);
    N = functionB(Y);
    c = function3(N);
}
```

Here the function1 is applied on each of the elements on the BigData and produce another two big data sets (X,Y). function2 and function3 are then applied operation individually on each of the elements on these X,Y data, respectively.

Since the operations of all the functions are applied on each of the elements of the data sets independently, using GPU might make it faster. So I come up with the following:

```
while( function(b,c)!=TRUE)
{
    //[X,Y] = function1(BigData);
    1. load kernel1 and BigData on the GPU. each of the thread will work on one of the data 
element and save the result on X and Y on GPU.

    //M = functionA(X);
    2a. load kernel2 on GPU. Each of the threads will work on one of the 
data elements of X and save the result on M on GPU. 
(workItems=n1, workgroup size=y1)

    //b = function2(M);
    2b. load kernel2 (Same kernel) on GPU. Each of the threads will work on 
one of the data elements of M and save the result on B on GPU
(workItems=n2, workgroup size=y2)
    3. read the data B on host variable b 

    //N = functionB(Y);
    4a. load kernel3 on GPU. Each of the threads will work on one of the 
data element of Y and save the result on N on GPU. 
(workItems=n1, workgroup size=y1)

    //c = function2(M);
    4b. load kernel3 (Same kernel) on GPU. Each of the threads will work
on one of the data element of M and save the result on C on GPU
(workItems=n2, workgroup size=y2)
    5. read the data C on host variable c
}
```

However, the overhead involved in this code seems significant to me (I have implemented a test program and run on a GPU). And if the kernels have some sort of synchronizations it might be ended up with more slowdown.

I also believe the workflow is kind of common. So what is the best practice to using OpenCL for speedup for a program like this.

Comment: cards can read + write + compute at the same time so you should make them concurrent where possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But as you see all the operations within the loop are depends on the result of previous operation. So, let us consider concurrency as you suggest is not possible. Is there any other way to improve it. Otherwise, what is the best practice.

Comment: In opencl 2.0, there is device side kernel enqueueing so it could be faster instead of waiting for host for each kernel init.

Comment: It looks like b and c only depend on BigData, why will function(b,c) change between iterations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a general problem with the way you've split up the problem into kernels, although it's hard to say as you haven't been very specific. How often do you expect your while loop to run?

If your kernels do negligible work but the outer loop is doing a lot of iterations, you may wish to combine the kernels into one, and do some number of iterations within the kernel itself, if that works for your problem.

Otherwise:

If you're getting unexpectedly bad performance, you most likely need to be looking at the efficiency of each of your kernels, and possibly their data access patterns. Unless neighbouring work items are reading/writing neighbouring data (ideally: 16 work items read 4 bytes each from a 64-byte cache line at a time) you're probably wasting memory bandwidth. If your kernels contain lots of conditionals or non-constant loop iterations, that will cost you, etc.

You don't specify what kind of runtimes you're getting, on what kind Of job size, (Tens? Thousands? Millions of arithmetic ops? How big are your data sets?) or what hardware. (Compute card? Laptop IGPU?) "Significant overhead" can mean a lot of different things. 5ms? 1 second?

Intel, nVidia and AMD all publish optimisation guides - have you read these?